# React hook set array from api directly to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

How can I set an array which I get from an api directly to a hook.
The api returns a complete array not pieces.

If I do it this way:

```
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(['']);

  const { data } = await axios.get(url, { headers });
  setFavorites(favorites => [...favorites, data.favorites]);
```

I get this output which is not correct:

```
(2) ["", Array(2)]
0: ""
1: (2) ["5ea42eae8750131824a5728f", "5ea5d29230778c1cd47e02dd"]
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I do not want to have an array inside the array.

Answer (score 2):

If `data.favorites` is an array as well you have to use spread in this case too.

```
setFavorites(favorites => [...favorites, ...data.favorites]);
```

Comment: This seems to work but the first array entry is empty `''`, how can I prevent that?

Comment: It starts filling at array positon [1] not [0]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(['']);

const { data } = await axios.get(url, { headers });
setFavorites(favorites => [...favorites, ...data.favorites]);
```

Comment: This seems to work but the first array entry is empty '', how can I prevent that?

Comment: It starts filling at array positon [1] not [0]